# Inserting rows in oracle livesql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am experimenting on https://livesql.oracle.com/ but got stuck with an error.
On executing `select * from customers;` I see the message `no data found`
When I run `INSERT INTO customers (customer_id, customer_name, city) VALUES (1, "name-1","city-1");` 
I get an error message `ORA-00984: column not allowed here`

What could be the reason for this? How can I insert values in the table?

Comment: Could you share the whole code? For example the creation of the table, too.

Comment: Please check the syntax of [Text Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA) (it's worth reading at least because it describes q-string format also)

Comment: Single quotes, not double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, strings are enclosed into **single quotes**:

```
INSERT INTO customers (customer_id, customer_name, city) 
VALUES 
(1, 'name-1', 'city-1');
```

---

You enclosed them into double quotes; to Oracle, it means that you actually specified **column names**.

Generally speaking, when working with Oracle you should omit double quotes (with identifiers) and avoid mixed letter case. You can create table e.g.

```
SQL> create table "Test" (ID number, "LastName" varchar2(20));

Table created.
```

but then you have to use double quotes and match letter case every time you access such a table:

```
SQL> insert into test (id, lastname) values (1, 'Littlefoot');
insert into test (id, lastname) values (1, 'Littlefoot')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> insert into "Test" (id, "LastName") values (1, 'Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

If you created it as

```
SQL> create table test (id number, LASTnAme varchar2(20));

Table created.
```

then you can write identifiers any way you want:

```
SQL> insert into teST (id, lasTNamE) values (1, 'Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL>
```